# What is "natural ordering"?

Tags: java, comparable, natural-sort

I have a class:

```
class Message {
  String id;
  Date sentDate;
  String clientName;
  String type; 
}
```

In my application, messages are sorted by `sentDate` for all use cases I have now and envision in the future.

Does that mean a natural ordering for a message is on `sentDate`, and the `Message` class can implement `Comparable` based on this field, or is there any formal definition of a natural ordering that my understanding does not correspond to?

I know that I can use Comparator, the reason I ask this question is to understand what question should I ask myself about class X, to understand whether objects of the class X have natural ordering by field Y.

Comment: I don't think SO is a good place to define how items should be  ordered in your particular case. If it would be C# and you are not sure what type of comparison to use you can simple always provide comparer to collections instead of relying on class to provide `Compare` method.Side note: consider specifying language tag...

Comment: As a matter of style I put the primary key first in the data type, in the order of significance if there is more than one.  You can default the natural order for your class to be anything you need it to be.

Comment: You have the right idea, but I could see it both ways. Natural ordering in the sense of Comparator has no formal definition; it is a subjective design judgment. You get to define whether there is a "natural ordering" for your objects, and if so, what it is. However, if someone sees you simply _sort_ a list of Messages, and is compelled to look up how you define comparison, then I would say it wasn't natural to them. If you get this feedback more than once, you probably want to revisit your choice.

Answer (score 5):

Natural ordering of Java objects is ordering based on `Comparable` interface implementation (i.e. method `compareTo`).

Answer (score 4):

Nautral order sorting is kind of an umbrella term that refers to the way that humans sort things. It most often refers to numbers (but not always) and how they are sorted contrasted with an ASCIIbetical sort.

#### List:

```
id2
id12
id1
```

#### ASCIIbetical Sorting:

```
id1
id12
id2
```

#### Natural Order Sorting:

```
id1
id2
id12
```